# AWS Transcribe API: 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I have a problem with AWS Transcribe
I try use it by PHP. My credentials have the full access for AWS tools. I have the this code:

```
 $response = $this->client->startTranscriptionJob([
        'LanguageCode' => 'en-US',
        'Media' => [
            'MediaFileUrl' =>  //S3 audio file path
        ],
        'MediaFormat' => 'mp3',
        'TranscriptionJobName' => 'JobName'
    ]);
```

But I receive error

[image]

Comment: I think you can submit files only from AWS S3, please check the URL,

Comment: @harishsharma I try so

Comment: What `MediaFileUrl` did you provide?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein S3 path of file. Path is worked when I try open it

Comment: The `MediaFileUrl` should look similar to: `https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/recording.wav`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes it is valid url

Comment: Well, the error message is saying that an invalid S3 URI was provided. Is the Transcoding request being sent to the same region as the S3 bucket region?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, yes, but the problem in valid the URL I open in the browser and it successfully opened

Comment: Even it is works in your browser, it needs to be in a format that is wanted by the Transcoding service. Please show us the _exact value_ of the `MediaFileUrl` you are providing (but you can change the bucket name to keep it private).

Answer (score 0):

you could get this error due to either

1) s3 object path is not valid

2) the s3 object does no exit

3) or the caller does not have permission to read the s3 object.